GraphQLResolveInfo' object has no attribute 'field_asts'"
So I am using graphene-django==3.1.2, which didn't let me importfrom graphql import ResolveInfo . Therefore, I used from graphql import GraphQLResolveInfo as ResolveInfo
However the error I see now is - GraphQLResolveInfo' object has no attribute 'field_asts'
Am I using the right equivalent of ResolveInfo?

Just wanna point this out that in JS I cannot find it either on the GraphQLResolveInfo field. I think it is missing for a reason, but dunno what is that reason . Did you have any luck finding an answer to your question?
